# Cannot Connect To AWS Elasticache Redis Cluster From Local Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, redis-cli, amazon-elasticache

I recently created a Redis cluster on AWS elasticache and am having trouble connecting via redis-cli from my local machine. Every time I run the command:

```
redis-cli -h <redis_cluster_domain> -p 6379
```

the connection is never established and eventually exits due to timeout.

Eventually, I figured it's blocking due to a setting on the security group, so I edited the inbound rules to allow all traffic from my IP address. Even after doing this I still cannot connect to the cluster. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Your VPC is blocking  the incoming connection

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.html

Comment: Do you have authentication enabled? Is it in a VPC? We need more detail.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary authentication is currently not enabled on this cluster and it is in a VPC. The VPC has IPv4 CIDRs enabled as well. Quick & dumb question - does my IP address need to be within the CIDR range?

Comment: Which CIDR range? If you defined one inside the inbound rules, then yes of course - get your current public IP and change the inbound rule to allow your IP - does that work?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I'm assuming the ip has to be within the CIDR range of the VPC and the subnet. Trying this now...let's see if it works. (I had to create a new subnet, VPC, security group, and redis cluster)

Comment: Your IP does not have to be within the CIDR range of the VPC no.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I still cannot connect. I added my IP address to the inbound rules for all traffic on the security group.

Comment: Do all IPs - does that work?

Comment: TCP 6379 allowed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238187/discussion-between-aaron-mednick-and-ermiya-eskandary).

Comment: Connecting to elasticache from the internet is actually a massive pain. I don't think you can connect, from the internet, without a VPN, or ssh tunnelling. The docs don't cover this well

Comment: It might need to be in a subnet not exposed to the internet, even when it is locked down by a security group

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out.

Apparently, you cannot access elasticache clusters from outside AWS by default. In order to do this, you need to create a VPN through AWS and connect to that in order to reach your desired cluster.

The steps to do this are outlined in this AWS tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws), but in more simple terms all I did was the following:

1. Create and import a certificate of authority using the AWS Certificate Manager. You will use this certificate to authorize your VPN connection.
2. Create a VPN Client Endpoint and attach the key and certificate generated in the previous step with it.
3. Associate the VPC being used on your elasticache cluster with the VPN endpoint.
4. Authorize all traffic on your VPN for all users.
5. Add a route to the route table of your VPN endpoint to allow access from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0).
6. Download VPN client configuration file locally and connect to the VPN using "openvpn" (you may need to brew install this) with your certificate and key created in the first step.

This worked for me and I'm glad I figured it out. Now I can connect to my Redis cluster from my local machine using "redis-cli"!

Answer (score 2):

you can also do this via a jump server / bastion host and even local port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to edit the Inbound rule in Network&Security of the Redis cluster. Also if you are using VPN, please ensure if you have made a TCP protocol entry.